# Is PayPal classic api still works?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a use case in which we need to transfer funds from our merchant account to our customer local bank.
I found [paypal legacy api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow-pro/) which says it can make ach transfers. 
I want to know how secure is using this legacy api and whether this is supported anymore or not.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is still functional and as mentioned on that page the PayPal Merchant Technical Services should be able to give you the most up to date guidance and direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it still works fine and will continue to work for a very long time.  Too many solutions up-and-running on it for them to dump it, and it's also still much more mature (loaded with more features) than REST.  They continue to add new features, too, so for REST to catch up it's going to a while.

Comment: Does this allow to transfer funds from a merchant account to our cutomer bank account?

Comment: No, you can't transfer straight to a bank account via the API.  You would need to send money to a PayPal account, and then they can transfer to their bank account through their PayPal account.

Answer (score 0):

REST API still needs lot of features, so I don't think that they will shut Classic API down soon.